# How set validation on size of string = 0 or min=5, max=10?

Tags: java, spring, validation, bean-validation

I need set validation on input of String field. This field should be an empty or between `5` to `10` characters. But if I set validation like this:

```
@Size(min=5, max=10)
private String couponCode;
```

It won't pass `@Valid` when the value is empty. How can I achieve that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can set a pattern to accept blank values or `5` to `10` characters:

```
@Pattern(regexp = "|.{5,10}")
private String couponCode;
```

Here we used *Alternation*, the `|`, to tell the validator to consider the passed value valid, if either empty string or `.{5,10}` patterns were matched.

If you consider blank values as empty strings, use the following pattern:

```
@Pattern(regexp = "\\s*|.{5,10}")
private String couponCode;
```